# AM - PM conflicts for comparision of dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, timestamp, between

Here I have a query which displays the datetime field as a result with the where condition in which two datetime fields getting compared.

```
SELECT req.created_on
  FROM incident req
 WHERE to_char(req.created_on ,'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss am')
       BETWEEN '20/05/2013 04:31:22 am' AND '23/05/2013 04:31:27 pm'
```

Data store in the database is "**2013-05-20 17:43:04("2013-05-20 05:43:04 pm")**".

The above query is returning data fine but if i change timestamp in first date from '**20/05/2013 04:31:22 am**' to '**20/05/2013 06:31:22 am**' it is returning null.

I don't know why this happening.

Comment: How did you change the timestamp? from half past four to half past six ?

Comment: @HughJones those search criteria dates. given by end user.
as you said i checked with the to_date() with two dates between which no date is present in databse. but still it is returning the value.

Comment: @HughJones
can any please help to convert 12 hr format string date to timestamp without timezone.

Comment: to_date('20/05/2013 04:31:22 am','DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS am')

Comment: Which is as Gordon has suggested below ...  Test it because I am working from memory

Comment: @HughJones i tried the to_date() earlier itself it is returning only date leaving the timestamp

Comment: Sorry - I have it wrong - you need `str_to_date('20/05/2013 04:31:22 am','DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS am')`

Comment: Still wrong - `STR_TO_DATE('01/5/2013 04:31:22','%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s')`

Answer (score 1):

You should do the conversion on the constants, not the column:

```
SELECT req.created_on
  FROM incident req
 WHERE req.created_on
       BETWEEN to_date('20/05/2013 04:31:22 am', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss am') AND 
               to_date('23/05/2013 04:31:27 pm', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss am')
```

Although this looks more cumbersome it has a key advantage in performance.  No, the advantage is not the overhead of converting a date to a string on every row (although there is some gain there).  The lack of function call around `req.created_on` means that an index can be considered for the query.  Wrapping it in a function often precludes the use of an index.

Comment: to_date() wont check on the timestamp. it will take only dates rt?
but i want the comparision on the timestamp along with the dates including am and pm also.

Comment: It will check the whole of the datetime

Comment: can any please help to convert 12 hr format string date to timestamp without timezone.

Comment: @Gokul Just change `to_date` in the answer above to `to_timestamp`

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto i tried that i gave like this 
    select to_timestamp('20/05/2013 08:00:00 pm','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from incident

instead of giving the result like "2013-05-20 20:00:00+05:30" it is giving like this "2013-05-20 08:00:00+05:30"

Comment: @Gokul You forgot the `am` at the end of the string: `select to_timestamp('20/05/2013 08:00:00 pm','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss am')`

Answer (score 0):

Don't convert your datetime field to a char.  Instead, convert those two strings to datetime objects and structure your query like this:

```
where req.created_on >= your first datetime object
and req.create_on < 1 second after your second datetime object
```

Comment: here the first date and the last date are coming form the server side. So they are string's that are coming for comparision.

Comment: Coming from what server side?  Is there a .net, coldfusion, php, whatever application you didn't mention?  If so, can you not send datetime objects instead of strings from that application?

Comment: Also, as Gordon mentioned, postgresql has a to_date() function you can use if necessary.

Comment: can any please help to convert 12 hr format string date to timestamp without timezone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take out the `to_char` and I would suggest you parameterise the input dates

so

```
  req.created_on Between :FirstDate and :SecondDate
```

(It is happening because the `between` clause is comparing two strings)

Comment: here the first date and the last date are coming form the server side. So they are string's that are coming for comparision.
I tried this one also

Comment: Using between on datetime objects will often cause you to miss data at or about the end datetime.

Comment: @DanBracuk is that a Postgres quirk ?

Comment: @Gokul Are you saying then that query you have posted was not the exact query you are having trouble with ?

Comment: @HughJones, it's not a Postgres quirk, it's just the way it goes with datetimes.

Comment: @DanBracuk You mean because there is nothing between '1-Jan-2013' and '1-Jan-2013' ?

Comment: @Gokul I think we need the exact query and a description of the environment it is being executed under; the problem is quite easy to solve but our answers may not be helping you.  What is the client?

Comment: @DanBracuk i used to_date() but this is returning only date leaving the timestamp aside. But i need the comparision along with the timestamp including am and pm.

Comment: @HughJones Extjs, i am using the postgres and 
    SELECT req.created_on
    FROM incident req
    WHERE to_char(req.created_on ,:dateFormatForGrid)
    BETWEEN '20/05/2013 04:31:22 am' AND '23/05/2013 04:31:27 pm'